# How to limit posts to 1 from each term with tax_query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, tax-query

Need 1 post from each.

```
<?php 

    global $post; // required

        $args = array (
            'tax_query' => array (
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array (
                    'taxonomy' =>'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array ('economy','the-constitution','monetary-policy','liberty')
                ),
                array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'highlight',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array ('lead','featured'),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
                )
            )
        );

        $posts = get_posts($args);

        foreach ($posts as $post) {

            setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <li class="post">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?><div class="imgframe"><?php the_post_thumbnail('PostThumbSideBar'); ?></div><?php else: endif; ?>
                <p class="meta"><?php the_category(' '); ?> <?php the_tags(' '); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>

    <?php } ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$categories = array('economy','the-constitution','monetary-policy','liberty');
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'category_name' => $category,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'highlight',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'lead','featured' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    );
    $wpse42358_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while( $wpse42358_query->have_posts() ) : $wpse42358_query->the_post();
        // write post stuff here
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

I opted to use WP_Query because you have more control on taxonomy queries.

Comment: Nice! 'relation' => 'AND' .. along with 'operator' => 'not in'(being added under terms) sealed the deal. Without those adjustments it wasn't working properly. If you wanna edit your answer to reflect those changes I'll award the answer - Thanks!

Comment: Good call. Actually now that I think about it, you probably do not even need `relation` because it is only one.